# Probability in quantum physics of a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, normalization

I have this time-dependent wave function from solving a 3-component Schrodinger's equation, $$\psi(t)=-\frac{2}{9}(-2, 1, 2)^T+\frac{2}{9}e^{3i\omega t}(2,2,1)^T+\frac{1}{9}e^{-3i\omega t}(1, -2, 2)^T$$

Clearly, $\psi(0)=(1,0,0)^T$ but the question that I had was what was the probability that the system is again in this state at time $t$? I am assuming what they meant by "this state" was that $\psi=(1,0,0)^T$. How should I approach this, what do I need to integrate over?

I found out that $|\psi|^2=1$ i.e., the wave function is normalised but does that do much?

Comment: Wouldn’t this be better asked on the Physics site?

Comment: I don’t know how $| \psi | ^2 = \frac{11}{3}$ is possible. The integral of $| \psi | ^2 $ over the state space should equal one, since $| \psi | ^2 $ is a probability density.

Comment: @Joe no, you are right, my apologies, some silly mistakes I made when calculating this..

Comment: I think that if you ask this on the physics site, you’ll get an answer much faster. I’m too rusty to give an answer, since I don’t recognize the state space for this problem.

Comment: Not need to integrate as your states are elements of a finite dimensional vector space with standard inner product.  see somment by @drer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the states be normalized, the probability of a given state is the square of the absolute value of the projection of the total state onto the given one. In your case it is: $$p=|\langle\psi(t)|\psi(0)\rangle|^2.$$

Can you take it from here?

> After straightforward calculation one obtains $$p=\left(\frac59+\frac49\cos 3\omega t\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check when will the second and third components vanish and solve for $t$ via observation: \begin{align}
-1+2 e^{3i\omega t}-e^{-3i\omega t}=0\\
-2+1 e^{3i\omega t}+e^{-3i\omega t}=0
\end{align}

You just want $e^{3i\omega t}=1$, $t=\frac{2 k \pi}{3\omega}$.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to find the time $t$ such that the system is *exactly* in the same state as initial one. Whereas the problem was to find the probability of being in this state at *arbitrary* time $t$.